# Lambda function with encrypted environment variable giving Decrypt error: InvalidCiphertextException: null

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-kms

I have a lambda function to establish a connection to atlas. The connection string is encrypted as an environment variable. When testing to establish a connection I get the following error:

```
2021-06-07T22:48:31.303Z    01ab146e-734f-4f06-a5e9-acfb5635bc3b    INFO    Decrypt error: InvalidCiphertextException: null
    at Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
  code: 'InvalidCiphertextException',
  time: 
  requestId: 
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 62.95362625619481
}
```

Below is partial code of the lambda function.

```
'use strict'

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

let atlas_connection_uri;
let cachedDb = null;

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var uri = process.env['MONGODB_ATLAS_CLUSTER_URI'];
    
    if (atlas_connection_uri != null) {
        processEvent(event, context, callback);
    } 
    else {
        const kms = new AWS.KMS();
                kms.decrypt({ CiphertextBlob: new Buffer(uri, 'base64') }, (err, data) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('Decrypt error:', err);
                        return callback(err);
                    }
                    atlas_connection_uri = data.Plaintext.toString('ascii');
            processEvent(event, context, callback);
        });
    } 
};
```

I think the issue may be because Buffer is deprecated but i'm not sure.

Any help provided would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not mongodb related question, I removed the tag. Is MONGODB_ATLAS_CLUSTER_URI defined? Can you decrypt it manually with aws cli?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Lambda has updated how to encrypt environment variables.

Found the solution [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/kms-invalidciphertextexception/)

Here is the break down:

Lambda passes the function name as the encryption context making the encrypt call to AWS KMS. For decrypt functions created before this change, you must update the code for decryption and pass the Lambda function name as encryption context.

To get the code with the decrypt call to AWS KMS for a specific SDK with the encryption context, follow these steps:

1. Open the Lambda console, and then choose Functions.
2. In Function name, choose the Lambda function.
3. In Environment variable, choose Edit, and then choose Add
   environment variable.
4. Enter a Key and Value, and then expand Encryption configuration.
5. Choose Enable helpers for encryption in transit, and then choose
   Encrypt.
6. Expand Decrypt secret snippet, copy and paste the snippet similar to the following:

   DECRYPTED = boto3.client('kms').decrypt(
   CiphertextBlob=b64decode(ENCRYPTED),
   EncryptionContext={'LambdaFunctionName': os.environ['AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME']}
   )['Plaintext'].decode('utf-8')

Use this code snippet to Decrypt new environment variables encrypted with encryption helpers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @MaxxABillion answer,
I add `LambdaFunctionName` to the `params` in the `kms.decrypt` function.
so in your case, it should look like this:

```
const functionName = process.env.AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME;
kms.decrypt({ 
  CiphertextBlob: new Buffer(uri, 'base64'),  
  EncryptionContext: { LambdaFunctionName: functionName }
})
```